# RtlSecureZeroMemory unresolved in static lib using MinGW

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, static-linking

I have a C static library compiled using MinGW. A `.a` file is generated and then used in a Visual Studio project. The static library uses `SecureZeroMemory` internally. The Visual Studio project runs into an issue where it cannot resolved `RtlSecureZeroMemory`, which is the function behind the `SecureZeroMemory` macro.

> LNK2019    unresolved external symbol RtlSecureZeroMemory referenced in function static_lib_memset_func

I would have thought that this function would have been in one of the libraries that Visual Studio adds by default (ex. `kernel32.dll`). But, using dependency walker, I cannot find this symbol.

What should my project include to get this working?

Comment: `RtlSecureZeroMemory` not function but macro defined in `winnt.h`

Comment: I am really confused. The DLL version of my library contains the code for `SecureZeroMemory` because it's inlined. So should the static library, in that case. Could this be a bug in MinGW?

Comment: again - **this is macro** are you include (indirect) `winnt.h` ? and search in your `winnt.h` `RtlSecureZeroMemory` symbol - `The implementation of RtlSecureZeroMemory is provided inline and can be used on any version of Windows (see WinNT.h.)`

Comment: That header is included and so is `windows.h`. The library compiles fine. It's the visual studio project that consumes the library that is giving the error.

Comment: Aha! When the library is compiled using MinGW, it refers to the `winnt.h` inside `%MINGW%\include` instead of the Windows SDK directory. There are differences in the two headers. The MinGW one has a declaration, but the body is only inlined if certain macros are provided.

Answer (score 0):

The function inside the static library was also marked `inline` when it called `SecureZeroMemory`. By removing the `inline` keyword, the problem went away. I think it has something to do with the fact that the `RtlSecureZeroMemory` was annoted as `extern inline __attribute__((__gnu_inline__))` and my function was also inlined.